# How can I make the current user the post author?

Tags: php, wordpress, user-registration, author

I want to automaticly create a post when a user registers. I use the code below and it works great. The only thing missing is that the post author needs to be the user that is creating the registration.

Can somebody help me to add a line to make the author of the post the current user? thank you!

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_216921_company_cpt', 10, 1 );

function wpse_216921_company_cpt( $user_id )
{
    // Get user info
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_roles = $user_info->roles;

    // New code added 
    $this_user_role = implode(', ', $user_roles );

    if ($this_user_role == 'author') {

        // Create a new post
        $user_post = array(
            'post_title'   => $user_info->nickname,
            'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
            'post_type'    => 'Team', // <- change to your cpt
        );
        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `'post_author'  => '$user_id` to your `$user_post`array.

```
// Create a new post
$user_post = array(
   'post_title'   => $user_info->nickname,
   'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
   'post_type'    => 'Team', // <- change to your cpt
   'post_author'  => $user_id
   );
```

Comment: Happy to help! Please consider accepting this or any other answer that solves the problem